# Applescript Backup Script

Tags: applescript

So my goal with this is to make a script that will make a folder showing the current date inside "1NF1N1T3 Backups" on my desktop and then copy the folder "1NF1N1T3 Server" on my desktop to the folder "1NF1N1T3 Backups". Currently it duplicates the "1NF1N1T3 Server" folder  and also creates the dated folder. I want "1NF1N1T3 Server" to be inside the dated folder, but I don't know what to do next. Please help and thanks to those that do help!

```
    tell application "Finder"
        set p to (path to desktop as text) & "1NF1N1T3 Backups"
        set d to date string of (current date)
        make new folder at p with properties {name:d}
        duplicate POSIX file "/Users/Jeremy/Desktop/1NF1N1T3 Server" to p
    end tell
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
set p to (path to desktop as text) & "1NF1N1T3 Backups"
set d to date string of (current date)

tell application "Finder"
    set newFolder to make new folder at p with properties {name:d}
    duplicate (POSIX file "/Users/Jeremy/Desktop/1NF1N1T3 Server" as text) to newFolder
end tell
```